# One quartz expression for a job executing at 13:30, 15:30, 18:00 everyday

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

Can it use one quartz expression to describe a job executing at 13:30, 15:30, 18:00 everyday?

Geln

Comment: -1 for making no apparent attempt at reading the documentation

Comment: "13:30, 15:30, 18:30 " => "0 30 13,15,18 * * ?", but "13:30, 15:30, 18:00" => ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with a single cron expression. You would need two, like `0 30 13,15 * *` and `0 0 18 * *`.

Comment: Thanks,but there is only one configuration for me to do it.

Comment: Can't you schedule the same job with two triggers?

Comment: The project framework has limit for that. I will try some other way to resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [Quartz Quick start guide.](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start)